# Use a protocol between a class and a view controller Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift-protocols

I worked with the library SwiftSocket to send messages to my server. When the connexion is established I want to create a callback to catch results. But my protocol is always null and the callback is not send.

This is my TCPClient class :

```
protocol ProtocolTCPClient {
    func connexionSucceeded()
}

class UtilsTCPClient {

    var delegate: ProtocolTCPClient?

    let client: TCPClient?

    init(address: String, port: Int32) {
        client = TCPClient(address: address, port: port)
        switch client!.connect(timeout: 5) {
        case .success:
            print("Success")
            if(delegate != nil){
                self.delegate?.connexionSucceeded()//never called
            } else{
                print("delegate nil")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: ")
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ViewController

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSocket

class ViewController: UIViewController, ProtocolTCPClient {

    var client: UtilsTCPClient?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.client = UtilsTCPClient(address: "server", port: 80)
        self.client?.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func connexionSucceeded(){
        print("Connexion succeeded")//never called
    }
 }
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: try debugging the `viewDidLoad` and see what happens when declaring the delegate

Comment: might be your TCPClient connection closure called before you assign delegate. Rewrite the init to send delegate in init itself.

Comment: It looks like your `client!.connect(timeout: 5)` is synchronous, so it will block the thread in the initialiser. This means that the delegate won't be set until after the connect method has executed and returned.  You should use asynchronous network operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should look like this.Because in your code first you init 'UtilsTCPClient' and then assigning delegate. And in 'UtilsTCPClient' you create 'TCPClient' and trying to access delegate but till it't not assigned so you should try the below code.

```
       protocol ProtocolTCPClient {
    func connexionSucceeded()
}

class UtilsTCPClient {

    var delegate: ProtocolTCPClient?

    let client: TCPClient?

    init(address: String, port: Int32, delegate: ProtocolTCPClient) {

        self.delegate = delegate

        client = TCPClient(address: address, port: port)

        switch client!.connect(timeout: 5) {
        case .success:
            print("Success")
            if(delegate != nil){
                self.delegate?.connexionSucceeded()
            } else{
                print("delegate nil")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: ")
            print(error)
        }

    }


}


class ViewController: UIViewController, ProtocolTCPClient {

    var client: UtilsTCPClient?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.client = UtilsTCPClient(address: "server", port: 80, delegate: self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func connexionSucceeded(){
        print("Connexion succeeded")//never called
    }
}
```